# Backbone event on button executing for all elements in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have a view class that I extend from Backbone.View and in the model I have the following button:

```
<a class="comment-btn delete-comment">Delete</a>
```

I associate the method to the buttons like this:

```
events:{
"click delete-comment":"deleteComment"
}
```

the problem is that when I click a button, the method is executed for every comment available in the page.

How can I make it to execute only on the item that was clicked?

Comment: Would be great if you could provide more info about your view, model etc.

Comment: Is the code in the click event really executed ? And can you change `events` hash to `"click .delete-comment":"deleteComment"` and give it a try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of scenario I generally add a 'data-id' attribute to each button and use that to determine which comment to action.

For example if the button was defined as:

```
<a class="comment-btn delete-comment" data-commentId="1">Delete</a>
```

The event handler would then determine the correct comment by evaluating the source of the event. Following example presumes use of jQuery:

```
deleteComment: function(event, args) {
   var id = $(this).data("commentId");
   ...
}
```

Comment: The event would still fire for views though wouldn't it? It's just that you can filter what to do by ID?

Comment: Yes, this would just allow you to filter cleanly, as I said in my comment yours is a better Backbone solution.

Answer (score 1):

What does your view look like? What is `el:` set to?

The events should be scoped to the current view.

Comment: Having a separate View instance per comment (which would always give the button event handler the correct scope) is a better solution than mine when using Backbone.